# Ionic 2/3 : How to programmatically uncheck a check box

Tags: ionic2

I have a situation wherein I have to uncheck a checkbox, onclick of a button.

This is my checkbox code

```
<ion-checkbox [checked]="!isChecked" [disabled]="!isdisabled" (ionChange)="saveProfile($event)" [(ngModel)]="default"></ion-checkbox>
```

I have tried using !iChecked, but it doesn't work. Basically, if the checkbox is already checked by the user, I want it to be unchecked (based on certain conditions) when you click a button.

```
<button class="button-m" (click)="navigateTo()" ion-button color="secondary"><ion-icon name="next">&nbsp;&nbsp;</ion-icon> Next </button>
```

TS file

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'choose-profile',
  templateUrl: 'choose-profile.html',
})
export class ChooseProfilePage {
  profileValue : string;
  isdisabled : boolean;
  isChecked :boolean;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private toastCtrl: ToastController) {

  } 
  getSelectedProfile(val){
    this.profileValue = val;

    if(this.profileValue!=undefined){
       this.isdisabled = true;
    }
    else{
      this.isdisabled = false;
    }
  }
  saveProfile(val){
    if(val.checked==true)
    {
     this.presentToast( this.profileValue+"set as default profile")
    }
    else
    {
      this.presentToast("No default profile")
    }
  }

  presentToast(val){
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: val,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  navigateTo()
  {
    console.log("Next Clicked")
    this.isChecked == true;
  }


}
```

Comment: Why not uncheck it on `navigateTo()`? Show your .ts file

Comment: That is where I am having the issue, it's not getting unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code. `this.isChecked == true;` does not set the `isChecked` variable to true. It merely does a comparison to check if `isChecked` is true.
You should use `=` instead of `==`.

Alter your code to be as following:

```
  navigateTo()
  {
    console.log("Next Clicked")
    this.isChecked = true;
  }
```

Comment: I just can't believe that I overlooked such a simple syntax issue. I should really take a break now :). Thanks for pointing it out! Please remove this question if doesn't add any value to the awesome community.

Comment: You can adjust the "checked" property but you should really be looking at the value from ngModel, that way you can write tests, changes, etc without the template

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `checked` attribute as a binding. Your input is bound with `ngModel` so what you need to do is change the value of that field.

I'm surprised after fixing the double equals your code worked because the template is looking for `default` and sets the checked attribute based on it's value. Create a variable and bind to it, then change it. I rewrote your component a bit

And then in your component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'choose-profile',
  templateUrl: 'choose-profile.html',
})
export class ChooseProfilePage {
  public shouldSaveProfile = false;
  profileValue : string;
  isdisabled : boolean;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private toastCtrl: ToastController) { } 
  getSelectedProfile(val){
    this.profileValue = val;
    this.isdisabled = this.profileValue ? true : false;
  }
  saveProfile(val){
    if(this.shouldSaveProfile)
       this.presentToast( this.profileValue+"set as default profile")

    else this.presentToast("No default profile")
  }

  presentToast(val){
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: val,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  navigateTo()
  {
    this.shouldSaveProfile = true;
    console.log("Next Clicked, should save value:", this.shouldSaveProfile);
  }
}
```